# Issue with Hugo theme when creating a website using blogdown

Tags: blogdown, hugo-theme

I am trying to create a website using blogdown package in R. I used the hugo theme `hugo-coder`. The repo is here - https://github.com/luizdepra/hugo-coder. Everything works as expected except for one issue. When I write a `blog` in `rmarkdown` file and save it in `posts` folder of `content` folder, it worked well except that no visualization is included when the website is completed. The codes for visualization are visible but the graphs are not visible when I finish building the site. Here is my repo for the website - https://github.com/msharifbd/BSAN405WEBSITE_SPRING2023.

I am just wondering whether someone can shed some light on this issue. Thanks.

Comment: First, see what `blogdown::check_site()` says. Second, I recommend that you use the file structure `name/index.Rmd` instead of `name.Rmd`, although both should work.

Comment: Good to know! Thanks for the confirmation!